# How to match database column with string

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

For example, I have a table like this:

```
id |      name      |
--------------------
1  | T              |
2  | Text           |
3  | A              |
4  | Text1 and Text |
5  | Txt            |
```

, and I want to reverse match column with string, something like this:

```
select * from table_name where %name% like 'Text1 and Text2 and Text3'
```

, and to get these results:

```
id | name |
-----------
1  | T | 
2  | Text |
4  | Text1 and Text |
```

How is that posible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE 'Text1 and Text2 and Text3' LIKE '%'||name||'%'
```

UPD Here is my SQLFiddle with example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d611f/1).